# Yii2: How to show a barcode?

Tags: yii2, barcode, barcode-printing

I have a function to print to PDF in my controller. It receives HTML code of a **bar code** and send it to _print-tags file.

**My controller file:**

```
public function actionPrintTags($barcode)
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = 'pdf';

    return $this->renderPartial('_print-tags', [
        'bar' => $barcode,
    ]);
}
```

**My _print-tags file:**

```
<body>
    <?= $bar . '<br/>' ?>
</body>
```

But it shows:

[image: Bad barcode]

If I show it in my view, it looks perfect:

[image: Perfect barcode.]

I use https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-barcode-generator-8-types.

**Update:** $barcode has the HTML code that create the barcode:

```
<div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 3px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 3px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 2px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 2px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 4px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF; height: 50px; width: 1px"></div><div style="float: left; font-size: 0px; width:0; border-left: 1px solid #000000; height: 50px;"></div><div style="clear:both; width: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">A</div>
```

Comment: What is in `$bar`? Looks like some styling issues.

Comment: add relevant code for the barcode you have added the code for the [**`Yii2-Pdf`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-pdf) according to docs you have to generate the bar code with the specific id of the element you want to display it in

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: the id is A.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably mPDF limitation. mPDF does not has full support for HTML and CSS features, some things may be rendered differently that in browsers.

> The CSS property `float` is **partially** supported in mPDF, allowing block elements (p, div etc.) to be placed alongside one another. They can also be used to create “columns” that span more than one page.
>
> Limitations:
>
> - Float only works properly if a width is set for the float
> - If no width is set, the width is set to the maximum available (full width, or less if floats already set)
> - A block element next to a float has the padding adjusted so that content fits in the remaining width.
> - Text next to float should wrap correctly, but backgrounds and borders will overlap and/or lie under the floats in a mess
> - Does not work if Columns are being used.
> - You cannot change the page margins/orientation etc. in middle of using floats
> - Float is only supported on block elements (i.e. not SPAN etc.)

https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/floating-blocks.html

---

You may try to play with this HTML and use some substitutes (like `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left`) or set some width for parent container. 
But it probably will be simper to switch to library which is able to render barcode as image ([picqer/php-barcode-generator](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator) for example) - simple PNG should be less problematic for PDF generators.